# Selecting even rows of specific css class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to select the even rows of a table of a certain class.

So the table looks like this:

```
Absolute row 1 -- virtual row 1 of class a
Absolute row 2 -- virtual row 2 of class a (should be matched by css selector)
Absolute row 3 -- virtual *row 1* of class b
Absolute row 4 -- virtual row 3 of class a
Absolute row 5 -- virtual row 4 of class a (should be matched by css selector)
```

I tried using this selector:

```
.table-result tbody tr.include:nth-child(even) {background-color: #eeeeee;}
```

but it still keeps the tr's with a different class in mind

Is there a way around this? Without having to resort to tables inside of tables?

HTML:

```
    <table class="ui-widget ui-widget-content table-result" id="adspaceresult">
        <thead>
            <tr class="ui-widget-header">
                <th>Type</th>

                <th>Info</th>

                <th>Average</th>

                <th>Bid</th>

                <th>Graph</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody id="adrbody">
            <tr class="include">
                <td><button data-adtype="1" data-adspaceid="2" class="resultbutton ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button"><span class="ui-button-text">Micro Bar<br>
                88x31</span></button></td>

                <td></td>

                <td>77</td>

                <td>Bid</td>

                <td>Graph</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">Why hello there!</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="include">
                <td><button data-adtype="1" data-adspaceid="3" class="resultbutton ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button"><span class="ui-button-text">Micro Bar<br>
                88x31</span></button></td>

                <td></td>

                <td>748102</td>

                <td>Bid</td>

                <td>Graph</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="include">
                <td><button data-adtype="1" data-adspaceid="5" class="resultbutton ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button"><span class="ui-button-text">Micro Bar<br>
                88x31</span></button></td>

                <td></td>

                <td>226</td>

                <td>Bid</td>

                <td>Graph</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="include">
                <td><button data-adtype="1" data-adspaceid="6" class="resultbutton ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button"><span class="ui-button-text">Micro Bar<br>
                88x31</span></button></td>

                <td></td>

                <td>6003</td>

                <td>Bid</td>

                <td>Graph</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

The tr containing the "why hello there" message should not be counted for.

Comment: The `child` and `of-type` selectors all behave like that. Anyway, need to see your HTML.

Comment: Is the table static or written out dynamically? If the latter, can you access the creating script to add another class?

Comment: Ok, added the html. It is dynamic. At first it only contains rows that are either even or uneven, but afterwards it adds a row that (from a ux point of view) actually belongs to the top row.

Answer (score 0):

select the rows by classname and select the alternate element

```
var list = $(".include")
for (i=0;i<list.length-1;i++)
 {
 if (i%2 == 0){
  // do what you want
 }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure all that can be condensed to one jQuery selector.

Comment: Internally that too is going to do the same

Answer (score 0):

Can be don't if you have limited number of rows, but I wouldn't advise using it

```
table .b, table .b~.b~.b, ... {background:white;}
table .b~.b, table .b~.b~.b~.b, ...{background:blue;}
```

example http://jsbin.com/exuzex/